# Replicate iOS iTunes Download Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation

When purchasing a song through the iTunes app on iOS, the user taps "Buy Now", and the song title appears to "lift" out of its cell and plop onto the "Downloads" tab bar item in a beautiful animation. I take that this is accomplished with Core Animation, but I'm unsure as to specifically what API to call to achieve a similar effect. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some quick code for you. The UIImage stands for 'the cart' in this example. The UILabel stands for 'the song'. A fully working project link is attached. Enjoy! :)

```
@interface AnimateViewController ()
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * cartImage;
@property(nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * songLabel;
@end

@implementation AnimateViewController
@synthesize cartImage;
@synthesize songLabel;

- (IBAction) initiateAddToCart:(id)sender{

    static float const curvingIntoCartAnimationDuration = 1.0f;

    CALayer * layerToAnimate = self.songLabel.layer;

    CAKeyframeAnimation * itemViewCurvingIntoCartAnimation = [self itemViewCurvingIntoCartAnimation];
    CABasicAnimation * itemViewShrinkingAnimation =  [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    itemViewShrinkingAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, self.songLabel.bounds.size.width/1.5, self.songLabel.bounds.size.height/1.5)];
    CABasicAnimation * itemAlphaFadeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    itemAlphaFadeAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];

    CAAnimationGroup * shrinkFadeAndCurveAnimation = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    [shrinkFadeAndCurveAnimation setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                            itemViewCurvingIntoCartAnimation,
                                            itemViewShrinkingAnimation,
                                            itemAlphaFadeAnimation,
                                            nil]];
    [shrinkFadeAndCurveAnimation setDuration:curvingIntoCartAnimationDuration];
    [shrinkFadeAndCurveAnimation setDelegate:self];
    [shrinkFadeAndCurveAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [shrinkFadeAndCurveAnimation setValue:@"shrinkAndCurveToAddToOrderAnimation" forKey:@"name"];
    [layerToAnimate addAnimation:shrinkFadeAndCurveAnimation forKey:nil];
}

- (CAKeyframeAnimation *) itemViewCurvingIntoCartAnimation {
    CGRect positionOfItemViewInView = self.songLabel.frame;

    float riseAbovePoint = 300.0f;

    CGPoint beginningPointOfQuadCurve = positionOfItemViewInView.origin;
    CGPoint endPointOfQuadCurve = CGPointMake(self.cartImage.frame.origin.x + self.cartImage.frame.size.width/2, self.cartImage.frame.origin.y + self.cartImage.frame.size.height/2) ;
    CGPoint controlPointOfQuadCurve = CGPointMake((beginningPointOfQuadCurve.x + endPointOfQuadCurve.x *2)/2, beginningPointOfQuadCurve.y -riseAbovePoint);

    UIBezierPath * quadBezierPathOfAnimation = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [quadBezierPathOfAnimation moveToPoint:beginningPointOfQuadCurve];
    [quadBezierPathOfAnimation addQuadCurveToPoint:endPointOfQuadCurve controlPoint:controlPointOfQuadCurve];

    CAKeyframeAnimation * itemViewCurvingIntoCartAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    itemViewCurvingIntoCartAnimation.path = quadBezierPathOfAnimation.CGPath;

    return itemViewCurvingIntoCartAnimation;
}

@end
```

Here- a fully working ARC/Storyboard project -http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/359564/itunesanimation.zip

Comment: Apart from not working with tab bar items (since they aren't views)  as the OP asked for and requiring the views to be siblings (since their frames aren't converted to the same coordinate space) it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The animation consists of many things, like getting the content of the view you are animating, scaling it, animating the position along a path etc. If you intent to animate the view down to a tab bar item or tool bar item then there is the extra problem that their frames aren't publicly available so you have to calculate the end position of your animation yourself.

I did all this in [a blog post](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/23234805389/unobtrusive-hints-of-joy) where I replicate the "Open in Background"-animation in Safari for iPhone. These two animation are visually very similar so I'm sure that you can learn a lot from that post.

Comment: link is broken :-\

Comment: @boliva that page (and the rest of that blog) no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the nitty gritty stuff. CoreAnimation - specifically using CA to animate either the UILabel or an image of the UILabel inside the cell along a path from the cell to the tab bar in an arc. You would also apply a scale transform to the animation so it looks like it shrinks into the tab bar.

There are many tutorials on the matter online. I suggest grabbing a book on CoreAnimation - check what it covers - most cover the basics which should definitely allow you to achieve the animation you want.

Hope this helps.